# "'groups' must be a factor" on Shapiro-Wilk test on Rcmdr

Tags: r

I am trying to run a shapiro-wilk normality test on R (Rcmdr to be more accurate) by going to "Statistics=>Summary=>Descriptive statistics" and then selecting one of my dependent variable and choosing "summary by group".

Rcmdr automatically triggers the following code :

> normalityTest(Algometre.J0 ~ Modalite, test="shapiro.test",
> data=Dataset)

And I am getting the following error message :

> 'groups' must be a factor.

I have already categorized my independant variable as a factor (I swear, I did !)

Any idea what's wrong ?
Thanx in advance

Here is what str(Dataset) shows :

```
'data.frame':   76 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Modalite    : chr  "C" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ Angle.J0    : num  20.1 20.5 21 22.5 19.1 ...
 $ Angle.J1    : num  21.7 22.6 22.8 23.3 20.5 ...
 $ Angle.J2    : num  22.3 23 23.9 24.2 21 ...
 $ Epaisseur.J0: num  1.97 1.54 1.76 1.89 1.53 1.87 1.54 2 1.79 1.41 ...
 $ Epaisseur.J1: num  2.07 1.49 1.87 1.91 1.54 1.9 1.51 2.03 1.71 1.48 ...
 $ Epaisseur.J2: num  2.08 1.69 1.77 2 1.61 1.99 1.38 2.06 1.86 1.53 ...
 $ Algometre.J0: num  45 40 105 165 66.3 ...
 $ Algometre.J1: num  32.7 39.7 91.7 124 63.7 ...
 $ Algometre.J2: num  51.3 58.7 101 138 60.3 ...
 $ ObsNumber   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

What does that mean ?

Comment: What does `str(Dataset)` show you?

Comment: So that tells you that `Modalite` is type character, not a factor. Try `Dataset$Modalite <- as.factor(Dataset$Modalite)` - but be careful that the levels are what you want - then try the test again.